# Permission denied on upload w/ IDE 2

Tags: uploading, ide

Dealing with this very common issue on IDE v2.0.0., but not sure why.

I should be fine group-wise:

```bash
adm tty dialout cdrom sudo dip plugdev lpadmin lxd sambashare docker
```

I've also seen numerous suggestions to change the device's permissions directly via `chmod a+rw /dev/<device>`. This is terrible advice, but nothing is working so far, so I tried it anyway. It also doesn't work, as at some point during the upload process, the device is removed and recreated, resetting the permissions.

edit: I've also ensured that ModemManager is not running, and has been purged from the system.

Running the IDE as root always fails, including when the `--no-sandbox` argument is passed.

I'm using the AppImage download on Ubuntu 22.04, but I tried the zip download, with the same results.

edit: Previously in this spot was a note about this problem not occurring on IDE v. 1.8. That wasn't actually the case - I was just testing with a board that doesn't remove and re-create the device on upload. Using a board where that does occur (Arduino Micro in this case), the error occurs in 1.8 as well.

Using `avrdude` directly (as my normal user account) also works just fine.

Additional observation - when the device is recreated by the OS after plugging the Arduino board in, it's first created with `crw------- 1 root root` permissions, and remains in that state for a very short period of time before switching to `crw-rw----+ 1 root dialout` permissions, at which point uploads work as expected.

Comment: You have since rebooted (or at least logged out and in) to be _certain_ that any chances you made to your group membership has been inherited to all processes involved?

Comment: @timemage I've been a member of those groups for literally years, so I have extreme confidence that all my groups are correct. This isn't the first time I've head to deal with this, but nothing is working this time around. Again, 1.8 works fine.

Comment: Well, I use the 2.0 IDE a little bit, but the system I'm no now is not Ubuntu, nor Debian based. If no new information shows up I may install Ubuntu in a VM may a USB device into it and see what happens when I try there. Given "using avrdude directly... works just fine", what exactly is producing this message? avrdude only as launched by the 2.0 IDE? When you tested avrdude did you test with a system installed one or the avrdude out of the .arduino15 directory? Do you see anything interesting in an strace?

Comment: What I'm seeing is that the `/dev/ttyACM0` device is being recreated by the OS when I connect the board in programming mode, first with permissions `crw------- 1 root root`, but a short time later (like within a second or so), those permissions switch over to the expected `crw-rw----+ 1 root dialout`. Because I am running avrdude directly after that switch has happened, it works, but for whatever reason, IDE 2.0 looks to be sending before the device permissions have settled, leading to the error. I don't know why the device goes through two sets of permissions like it does, though.

Comment: I don't know that it does this (I'm not sure why it would), but can you verify that ModemManager is not enabled. It's not something you want running anyway.

Comment: Ah forgot to mention that in the original message, but yeah, ModemManager has already been purged from the system.

Comment: Installed Ubuntu 22.04 in an VM, disabled ModemManger, added myself to dialout, restarted to take effect, dowloaded non-appimage IDE 2.0.0 zipfile. unpacked, ran, mapped in an UNO on USB, compiled/uploaded a blink sketch twice with different blink rates. No permission errors. Are you running something like selinux, containers, modified posix capabilities, apparmor, etc?

Comment: I've not modified anything in this install that I'm aware of. Does your USB device get removed and re-created each upload? That is the core of this problem. I'm watching the file via `watch -n 0.1 ls -l /dev/ttyACM0`, then starting an upload. It's the short window of `crw------- 1 root root` permissions immediately upon creation of the device that seems to be the issue here. Everything is fine once the permissions settle, but I do not know what mechanism causes this. I assume it's in the OS, but _many_ searches on this have come up with nothing.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/139598/discussion-between-timemage-and-x1a4).

Comment: I thought you were going to post something. But, sure I can. It'll take a little bit, but I'll put something basic up first.

Comment: oh I can make a post. I just wanted to give credit where it was due

Comment: The reason why I'm thinking you want to is that you then have more freedom to clean up the question. I'd feel weird editing your question to the degree that I'd be inclined to in order to make the answer match  cleanly with it.

Comment: fair enough. i'll take care of it

Comment: You can drop all the Edit: stuff. So there's no saga to follow. Just have it be the symptom that people are likely to find with search terms and then move all the answer material into an answer. Offhand the only input I have on the answer is that it's solvable at different levels. One is removing the package entirely another being the specific edit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After a [long debugging session in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/139598/discussion-between-timemage-and-x1a4), we've determined that a udev entry installed by the `apt` package [laptop-mode-tools](https://github.com/rickysarraf/laptop-mode-tools) takes a long time to run, leading to the permissions not settling on the USB device until after the IDE has attempted to upload.

This problem happens even when laptop-mode isn't enabled because you're e.g. using AC. You don't need to be actually using a laptop for this problem to occur, as laptop-mode-tools is a generic power-saving package that can be installed anywhere.

The udev rule in question is `ACTION=="add", SUBSYSTEM=="usb", RUN+="lmt-udev force"` in the file  `/lib/udev/rules.d/99-laptop-mode.rules`.

Commenting out that udev rule, or changing `force` to `auto` resolves the problem for me (without needing to restart udev, or anything else).

Larger hammers that can be used to resolve this include setting `ENABLE_LAPTOP_MODE_TOOLS` to `0` in `/etc/laptop-mode/laptop-mode.conf`, or simply removing `laptop-mode-tools` from the system entirely.

@timemage gets the credit for this fix.

Comment: Yeah. An Arduino user stands chance of finding this avoiding some grief with it. I may tack on some comments later that you can integrate (or not). The only one I'll mention now is just that this problem will not be particularly noticeable for a board that with a dedicated serial transceiver, e.g. the UNO, NANO, Mega, ESP8266 boards, because they don't re-enumerate on the USB bus during each reset/upload. Once the permissions become correct (quickly or slowly) the remain correct until disconnected.